# C++ virtual function passing and factory function

Tags: c++, function, class, virtual, factory

I'm struggling with the last part of a homework problem and I'm getting the error

```
error: passing ‘const string {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
    nm = name_str;
```

The constructor in question is

```
Pilot::Pilot(std::string name_str): Aircrew(nm)
    {
            nm = name_str;

    };
```

with factory function

```
Aircrew *Aircrew::makeAircrew(char ch, std::string name_str){
            if(ch == 'P')
                    return new Pilot(name_str);
```

in the header file I have

```
class Aircrew
{
public:
    Aircrew(std::string name_str);
    virtual const std::string type(void) const = 0;
    virtual const int maxFlights(void) const = 0;
    const double maxHours(void) const;
    const std::string name(void) const;
    void setFlights(int i);
    void setHours(double h);
    void print(void) const;
    virtual void scheduleFlight(int f, double h) const;
    static Aircrew* makeAircrew(char ch, std::string name_str);
    virtual ~Aircrew(void);
protected:
    const std::string nm;
    int flightsTaken;
    double hoursWorked;
};

class Pilot: public Aircrew
{
public:
    Pilot(std::string name_str);
    virtual const std::string type(void) const;
    virtual const int maxFlights(void) const;
};
```

Now per the factory function I'm trying to pass a name along to the const nm string but I'm struggling with how to do that. I've been googling to no avail. The goal is to pass name_str to nm so that in the member function name i can do.

```
  const string Aircrew::name(void) const{
            return nm;
    }
```

Note: I can't change anything in the header files as per the professor. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but two immediate problems with your `Pilot` constructor are (i) You are passing `nm` to the base class constructor which has not been initialized (ii) you are trying to assign to a constant string. Both of these would be fixed by `Pilot::Pilot(std::string name_str): Aircrew(name_str) {}`

Comment: I'd find it pretty hard to trust any professor who produces a class like we see here in `Aircrew`.

Comment: The trick @ChrisD is using to initialize `nm` is the astoundingly under-taught [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)